# Dynamic multi level component rendering in Angular

Tags: angular

We are able to build angular app (version 4.3.6) dynamically on read of json data wherein the application tree structure inlcudes only one level of children. We are doing this using `ComponentResolverFactory`.

We wanted to try the same with nested children where in one component has multiple children, and some of the children can have even further children.

Json data structure is similar to the below structure.

```
var config = {
  components: [
    {
      type: "tab-group", //name of the component, with this name we can find out the actual Component class.
      data: {},
      children: [ //These are the children of "tab-group" component
        {
          type: "tab", //First child of the "tab-group" component.
          data: { //This data needs to be provided to the component when we add it to the View
            header:'...'
          },
          children: [
            {
              type: "text-input",
              data: {
               name:'...',
               label:'...',
               ...
              }
            },
             {
              type: "select",
              data: {
               name:'...',
               label:'...',
               ...
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this recently and you can use this snippet with some tweaks for your scenario:

```
addDynamicComponent(comp, viewContainerRef) {

    const factory = this.factoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(comp);
    const component = factory.create(viewContainerRef.parentInjector);

    viewContainerRef.insert(component.hostView);

    return component;
  }

ngOnInit() {
  this.loadRecursively(this.config.components);
}

load(type: string): Promise<any> {

  // Swap the path for your app structure, this will fetch the component to use
  return System.import(`../${type}/${type}.component`)
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    }
  );
}

 loadRecursively(components, view) {

    for (const component of components) {

      this.load(component.type).then((loadedData) => {

        const component = loadedData[component.componentName];
        const loadedComponent: any = this.addDynamicComponent(component, view);

        // Swap ._id for some unique identifier for the component
        this.instances[component._id] = loadedComponent.instance;

        if (component.children.length) {
          this.loadRecursively(component.children, loadedComponent.instance.viewContainerRef);
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

**EDIT:**

```
<ng-template #dynamic></ng-template>

@ViewChild('dynamic', {read: ViewContainerRef}) viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef;
```

Comment: Thanks @Chrillewoodz. Could you please let me know how we can get the reference to "viewContainerRef" from component.instance?

Comment: @NivedithaR Added code for determinating where to load the component.